# In C++, how do you obtain an iterator on the second element of a vector of pair

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `std::vector<std::pair<int,double>>`, is there a quick way in terms of code length and speed to obtain:

- a `std::vector<double>`on the second element
- a `std::vector<double>::const_iterator`on the second element without creating a new vector

I did not manage to find a similar question in the list of questions highlighted when typing the question.

Comment: With regards to your question title; if you want an iterator on the contents of a datastructure held in a container, you're going to have to write one yourself by wrapping up a standard vector iterator. I don't see how you can implement your first request without doing an iterate'n'copy. I don't see how you can do the second request _at all_; you will need a custom iterator surely.

Comment: @Rook: I was actually looking for something like ronag's solution. Should I edit my post ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first question, you can use transform (with a lambda from c++11 in my example below).
For the second question, i don't think you can have that.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {

    std::vector<std::pair<int,double>> a;

    a.push_back(std::make_pair(1,3.14));
    a.push_back(std::make_pair(2, 2.718));

    std::vector<double> b(a.size());
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), [](std::pair<int, double> p){return p.second;});
    for(double d : b)
        std::cout << d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is something like:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,double>> a;

auto a_it = a | boost::adaptors::transformed([](const std::pair<int, double>& p){return p.second;});
```

Which will create a transform iterator over the container (iterating over doubles), without creating a copy of the container.

Comment: Well, at least a small mentioning that this requires an external library called *boost* would be a good idea instead of just using magic unknown names in the code sample.

Comment: @ChristianRau: It kind of says itself doesn't it? `boost::`.

Comment: Yeah, given he has already heard about *boost* (which is indeed likely, I admit).

Comment: This seems the easiest one rather than writing a generic wrapper yourself.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I can think about at the moment would be something like:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> foo{ { 1, 0.1 }, { 2, 1.2 }, { 3, 2.3 } };

std::vector<double> bar;
for (auto p : foo)
    bar.emplace_back(p.second);
```

Answer (score 0):

My way :

```
std::pair<int,double> p;
std::vector<std::pair<int,double>> vv;  
std::vector<std::pair<int,double>>::iterator ivv;

for (int count=1; count < 10; count++)
{
    p.first = count;
    p.second = 2.34 * count;
    vv.push_back(p);
}

ivv = vv.begin();
for ( ; ivv != vv.end(); ivv++)
{
    printf ( "first : %d  second : %f", (*ivv).first, (*ivv).second );
}
```